# Excel VBA - How to automate check and select duplicates in multiple lists in multiple sheets in one workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

How to automate **check for duplicates** in **multiple lists** in **multiple sheets** in the same workbook?

I've managed to make it work semi-automatically by having a macro for each comparison that I need. That means a macro for finding duplicate values between:

```
Worksheets("All").Range("Annie") and Worksheets("Annie").Range("A:A")
Worksheets("All").Range("Benny") and Worksheets("Benny").Range("A:A")
```

etc.
etc..

[Here is a screenshot that shows where I'm at, and hopefully visualizes what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNjf3.png)

(Annie's been to Sweden and Kenya - therefore those countries are marked red by the macro)
(Benny's been to Russia and Spain)
(And so forth)

It would be much more efficient to make just ONE code, that does this for all columns that has values in `Worksheets("All").` I need to be able to have at least 50 columns with names (Annie, Benny, Charlie, Danny, Emma, Fabian, etc., etc..)

Is this possible?

Here is my code, so far (for "Benny"):

```
Sub findDuplicatesBenny()

Dim rng1, rng2, cell1, cell2 As Range

Set rng1 = Worksheets("All").Range("Benny")

Set rng2 = Worksheets("Benny").Range("A:A")

For Each cell1 In rng1
If IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then Exit For

For Each cell2 In rng2
If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then Exit For
If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then

cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
cell1.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
End If

Next cell2
Next cell1

End Sub
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: This can be done with conditional formatting, avoiding VBA entirely. Are you open to that?

Comment: Hi @BigBen - thanks for your reply! Definitely open to learning that as well. I have no preferences on how to make this work. I’ll go with whatever solution is most optimal.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with conditional formatting, you can use `INDIRECT` and the name (Annie, Benny, etc.) in row 1 to create a reference to each name's respective sheet. Then with `COUNTIF` you can count duplicates.

1. Under *Conditional Formatting*, click *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.
2. Enter the following formula: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&A$1&"'!A:A"),A1)`

[image]

3. Click *Format* to apply the coloring you want.
4. In the *Rules Manager* window, change the "*Applies to*" range reference as needed.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Just to explain more thoroughly... Two main parts to this formula:

1. [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34): used to count the number of cells that match a criterion. Ignoring the `INDIRECT` for the moment, and using the example of cell `A2`, the formula above is equivalent to `=COUNTIF(Annie!A:A,A2)`, which looks at column `A` on the `Annie` sheet and counts all instances of `Sweden`. That would return `1`.

[image]

And if you were to drag that formula down, in `A3` it would return `1` for `Kenya`, in `A4`, `0` for USA and so on.

In another column, you could create a similar `COUNTIF` referencing `Benny`, with similar results - `0` for Sweden, all the way down to `1` for Russia and Spain.

[image]

---

2. [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261): returns the reference specified by a text string. The above formula uses `INDIRECT` to make the sheet and range reference (`Annie!A:A`, `Benny!A:A` and so on) dynamic.

First to explain the text string: `"'"&A$1&"'!A:A"`. That results in `'Annie'!A:A` and `'Benny'!A:A` and so on:

[image]

Used inside `INDIRECT` these text references become range references. By wrapping the `INDIRECT` in a `COUNTIF`, the formula effectively is equivalent to the `=COUNTIF(Annie!A:A,A2)` above - we've just made the `Annie!A:A` dynamic. Note that I include a single quote `'` before and after - `'Annie'!A:A`. This is needed if a sheet name has a space in it, e.g. if the name is `Annie Marie`.

---

As for the conditional formatting - formatting is applied if the formula input evaluates to `TRUE`. I'm using a slight trick that a `0` in conditional formatting is equivalent to `FALSE` and 1 or more is `TRUE`. So the formatting will be applied to any cell where the `COUNTIF` returns a 1 or more. That's how duplicates are flagged/filled.

Comment: Hi @BigBen Thank you very much for this much more efficient and short code solution! It works great! 

Now I am just trying to understand _how_ it works. So far this is what I understand (or think, that I understand) from your formula:

`COUNTIF()` Count cells that match criteria;
`INDIRECT()` Create a reference from text;
`COUNTIF(INDIRECT())` Count cells that match the criteria referenced to from text; 
`"'"&A$1&"'"` _Would you mind explaining what this means?_;
`!A:A` Column A in currently active sheet.

Comment: Sure, I'll use cell A2 as an example. Say you enter `=COUNTIF(Annie!A:A,A2)` off to the side - it returns 1, so you know Sweden is a duplicate. The formula with `INDIRECT` recreates this `COUNTIF`, but allows the sheet name `Annie` to become dynamic. You want the text inside the `INDIRECT` to look like `Annie!A:A`. You can get the `Annie` portion from `A$1` of the current sheet. Then you need a single quote `'` before and after the sheet name (to handle the possibility of the sheet name having a space in it, e.g. Anne Marie), then an exclamation point, then the `A:A`.

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation and I'll add to my answer :)

Comment: Hi @BigBen Thanks for elaborating! I don't fully understand yet, as I'm very new to this, but you've definitely provided me with some valuable inputs to work on. I'll have a fresh look at this formula, and your elaboration, tomorrow morning, when my brain is well rested again :-P Cheers!